# How to define scalar variable in sql query according to row?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

I have a table named `raporal` from which I need to show `birimmaliyet` and `enerji/metrekare`.

That's why I have written a query that is given below. But I am getting the result of each query same result "1.5". Result of each row is same.

I have no idea how to solve this. Can anyone please help me on this? I need your help very much.

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @enerjimetrekare decimal

SET @enerjimetrekare = (select((Max(enerjiküm)-min(enerjiküm))/ Max(üretimmik))from raporal)

SELECT 
    Ürün, 
    MAX(ÜretimMik) As üretim_mik, 
    Ebat, 
    (max(enerjiküm)- min(enerjiküm)) as EnerjiTüketim,
    @enerjimetrekare * 1.5 as Birimmaliyet,
    cast(((cast(Max(enerjiküm)as decimal(5,2)))
                - cast(min(enerjiküm)as decimal(5,2)))
            / cast(Max(üretimmik)as decimal(5,2)) as numeric (36,2)) as "enerji/metrekare" 
FROM raporal    
WHERE ÜretimMik is not null and ÜretimMik<>0
GROUP BY Ürün,ebat
```

Result is:

```
BirimMaliyet | enerji/metrekare    
   1.5         | 0.74
   1.5         | 0.00
   1.5         | 0.72
   1.5         | 1.98
   1.5         | 1.68
   1.5         | 0.00
   1.5         | 1.70
```

I want to table this: (enerji/metrekare (according to product) * 1,5)

```
  BirimMaliyet | enerji/metrekare
  1.11         | 0.74
  0.00         | 0.00
  1.08         | 0.72
  2.97         | 1.98
  2.52         | 1.68
  0.00         | 0.00
  2.55         | 1.70
```

Comment: It's your use of comma here `@enerjimetrekare * 1,5 as Birimmaliyet` do you mean `@enerjimetrekare * 1.5 as Birimmaliyet`

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But all of result will be 1.5.

Comment: It's because you're first calculating a constant value for @enerjiemetrekare (your SET statement), and then using that in your query, so it's not relative to rows in your results. You need to calculate it for each row, possibly using windowing functions to get aggregates for enerjieküm and üretimmik for the product on each row.

Comment: I also want to learn how to do this. How can I use  new created column (for examp.  'enerji/metrekare') in equation? Is there a way to do this? If can I use 'enerji/metrekare' I can solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (@sasfrog described your problem quite well!):

```
SELECT
  Ürün,
  MAX(ÜretimMik) AS üretim_mik,
  Ebat,
  MAX(enerjiküm) - MIN(enerjiküm) AS EnerjiTüketim,
  ( ( MAX(enerjiküm) - MIN(enerjiküm) ) / MAX(üretimmik) ) * 1.5 AS Birimmaliyet,
  CAST((( CAST(MAX(enerjiküm) AS DECIMAL(5, 2))) - CAST(MIN(enerjiküm) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)))
  /CAST(MAX(üretimmik) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS [enerji/metrekare]
FROM
  raporal
WHERE
  ÜretimMik IS NOT NULL
  AND ÜretimMik <> 0
GROUP BY
  Ürün,
  ebat
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But some command must be change. After code is working.